# nvidia-smi fails when an incompatible nvml library included

Tags: cuda, dynamic-linking

Accidentally an incompatible `nvml` library was added to the library path in a linux environment. In that setup when I try to query `nvidia-smi`, it gives out the following error

`Failed to initialize NVML: Driver/library version mismatch`

And when I remove that incompatible library from the library path and query `nvidia-smi` again, the query runs successfully and the output is displayed as expected.

Yet, when I look into the dependent libraries by entering `ldd` for `nvidia-smi` it does not show that the process depends on the `nvml` library.

```
$>ldd /usr/bin/nvidia-smi 
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffa84db000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f58ba044000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f58b9e3f000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f58b9a7e000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007f58b9876000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f58ba27d000)
```

If it does not depend on the `nvml` library, why does it give out an error when there is an incompatible `nvml` library?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ldd` provides a list of application dependencies on libraries that are *dynamically* linked to the application.

Presumably this application uses [runtime loading](https://www.dwheeler.com/program-library/Program-Library-HOWTO/x172.html) of a (shared) library (for example, `strace nvidia-smi 2>&1 |grep ml`)

When loading a library at runtime, it is not necessary to explicitly link the application against the library, and the library will not show up as a dependency in `ldd` output (if it is not explicitly linked at application build time).